# Generated Admin does not work with Generated "AUTO" Id field

Tags: php, sonata-admin

This is the entity:

```
<?php
// src/Alvent/LocalBundle/Entity/Note.php
namespace Alvent\LocalBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Notes")
 */
 class Note
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $Id;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */ 
    protected $Note;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=50)
     */ 
    protected $Date;

     //***************************************************************************************
     //Getters and Setters
     //***************************************************************************************

    /**
     * Get Id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }


    /**
     * Set Note
     *
     * @param string $notes
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setNote($note)
    {
        $this->Note = $note;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Notes
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNote()
    {
        return $this->Note;
    }


    /**
     * Set Date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Notes
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->Date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->Date;
    }
}
```

Ths is the generated admin for the entity:

```
<?php

namespace Alvent\LocalBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class NoteAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('Id')
            ->add('Note')
            ->add('Date')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('Id')
            ->add('Note')
            ->add('Date')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('Id')
            ->add('Note')
            ->add('Date')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('Id')
            ->add('Note')
            ->add('Date')
        ;
    }
}
```

In the create form the ID field shows with no value, it does not let me save without input a value, and when I do, it does not like it barbecue I have not setId functions (which I shouldn't).

Neither the property `Id` nor one of the methods `addId()`/`removeId()`, `setId()`, `id()`, `__set()` or `__call()` exist and have public access in class `Alvent\LocalBundle\Entity\Note`.

> 500 Internal Server Error - NoSuchPropertyException

I tries a lot of stuff like hide the Id field, remove it, etc. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Of course once i post the question, I figured one way:  ->add('Id','hidden',array('data' => null)) which avoids the ID on the form and also sets it to null which bypasses the validation and lets doctrine to generate the number.However it does not work when i came back to edit :(

Comment: OK. so this is what i ended up doing:       ->add('id', 'integer', array('required' => false,  'attr' => array('readonly' => true))) and it works :)